# Create valid JSON from multiple objects

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have the next code, which generate objects one by one:

```
...

    .data(function(data) {
         //data is object: {name: Bruce, surname: Lee}
         fs.appendFile('./test.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), function(err) {
             console.log(err);
         });
    })

...
```

After that I have my test.JSON file with the next syntax:

```
{"name": "Bruce", "surname": "Lee"}{"name": "Bruce", "surname": "Lee"}{"name": "Bruce", "surname": "Lee"}
```

Many single objects, JSON is not valid... How can I add commas after every single object or make my JSON valid?

Expected result:

```
{
    {"name": "Bruce", "surname": "Lee"},
    {"name": "Bruce", "surname": "Lee"},
    {"name": "Bruce", "surname": "Lee"}
}
```

or

```
{
   "entity": {"name": "Bruce", "surname": "Lee"},
   "entity": {"name": "Bruce", "surname": "Lee"},
   "entity": {"name": "Bruce", "surname": "Lee"},
}
```

Which one will be more usable and correct?

Comment: can you add the expected JSON ?

Comment: Do you write these objects in a loop?

Comment: You are using `appendFile` in a loop or at least multiple times. You can store all your object in an array and then call `JSON.stringify()` or you can call `fs.appendFile('./test.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) + ',', function(err){}); `

Comment: @marvel308 added

Comment: that is not valid, do you need an array instead of an object ?

Comment: @marvel308 No, I need JSON file,,, How It will be better?

Comment: @AngryB Made an edit for the valid json data

Comment: @alexmac yes, It is a part of parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single entity request Should be like below: Single Object

```
{"name": "Bruce", "surname": "Lee"}
```

Multiple entity should be like below: Multiple Objects

```
[
    {"name": "Bruce", "surname": "Lee"},
    {"name": "Bruce", "surname": "Lee"},
    {"name": "Bruce", "surname": "Lee"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would produce an array of objects

```
[
    {"name": "Bruce", "surname": "Lee"},
    {"name": "Bruce", "surname": "Lee"},
    {"name": "Bruce", "surname": "Lee"}
]
```

This would produce and object that contains other objects with the property names "entity_1" "entity_2" ect.

```
{
    "entity_1": {"name": "Bruce", "surname": "Lee"},
    "entity_2": {"name": "Bruce", "surname": "Lee"},
    "entity_3": {"name": "Bruce", "surname": "Lee"},
}
```